# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow - python3.9 64bit

Tags: macos, tensorflow, pip

I'm trying to use Tensorflow for some federated learning purposes, but I can't successfully install it using pip.

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Error message I get is:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

I'm running a virtual environment with Python3.9.10 and I'm working from an M1 Mac.

I've looked into similar posts ([I would like to install tensorflow but this message appears: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70570590/6355143)) where it suggested to check the python version and even trying `tf-nightly` instead. I've done this with no success.

Answer (score 12):

There are no files for arm64 available for tensorflow on [the tensorflow pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#files)
There is a [guide](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/) on how to install tensorflow to be run on Mac though. You would need `conda` though:

```bash
conda create -n TFmacOS python=3.9 pip
conda activate TFmacOS 
conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps==2.7.0
python -m pip install tensorflow-macos==2.7.0
python -m pip install tensorflow-metal
```

**EDIT:**
The above information is outdated and only valid for tensorflow < 2.12. Starting from tensorflow 2.12., there are arm64 whl files on the relevant pypi page and tensorflow can be installed directly. It is still advisable though to install the metal plugin for acceleration on Apple chips (see guide linked above for detail)

```
python -m pip install tensorflow-metal
```